# Visual Studio Code Can't Open | Macbook Pro 2019

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am facing a weird bug/error. I can't open visual studio code anymore! Can't understand why it's happening. In vscode icon, it just shows a question mark.

[image]

Comment: broken symlink? have you tried to start vscode in another way, for example from command line oder by executing the vscode binary file?

Comment: yes, i tried and vscode doesn't show as an application !

Comment: maybe a reinstall can fix it quick ... make a backup of your vscode user settings folder and of your extensions folder, then reinstall, launch vscode and if it works fine, paste your backups and try launching again

Comment: Yes, In application there is no visual studio code app ! But i'm wondering why it's happening..